# Time spent in initializing all elements of an array to zero in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am initializing all the elements of an array to zero many times in my program.

I am using this code:

```
int a[100000]={};
```

Is the code above faster than this code:

```
for(int i=0; i<100000; i++)
{
    a[i]=0;
}
```

Or is there any other way to do it which is faster than both of them?

Comment: This definition a[100000]={}; is wrong. You have to specify the type specifier for  the array because the answer depends on the type specifier

Comment: I am using int and i did specify it in my my program. I just forgot to write it here.

Comment: I would choose the first one because it is more concise. But if you want to know about performance, measure both.

Comment: You could also inspect assembly for both; if they both generate the same code then there is no point benchmarking

Comment: Is my question that bad that everyone is down voting it?

Comment: Yes. Want to know which is faster? Measure it.

Comment: @n.m. I also wanted to know if there is any other way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually compilers for definitions like this (when the array has automatic storage duration)

```
int a[100000]={};
```

generate object code that equivalent to

```
memset( a, 0, sizeof( a ) );
```

For example AFAIK in IBM Mainframe this function is implemented with one mashine instruction.

Comment: So does it mean it is faster than "for" loop?

Comment: @Priyansh Gangwar Yes it can be much faster because for example in IBM mainframe function memset can be implemented using only one mashine instruction.

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention, how you can self evaluate time of anything (synch executed) you want.
Pseudo:

```
DateTime begin = DateTime.Now;

// Your operations (for example 1 000 000 of them ... )

DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan operationsTakeOver = end - begin;
```

And then you don't have to ask here performance questions. Of course in most of the cases.